# VOLTTRON: `python3 bootstrap.py` Does not install all packages

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, volttron

I am in the process of installing VOLTTRON on my raspberry Pi. I came across this [VOLTTON installation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zHG1p76GNs&list=TLGG8TyZC8fiYxMwMTAzMjAyMw&t=4s&ab_channel=PNNLUnplugged) and followed the same steps. But my installation is running into some issues:

On a Linux machine, as shown in the installation video: It installed all packages without any errors and I observed seven bars (showing the installation progress)
[image]

On my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B machine: installed few packages initially and then it stops with errors.
[image]

I need your help to understand what went wrong. I repeated the installation 2 to 3 times and I don't know if error is to with this. But there is one error message I clearly see is `ERROR: you must give atleast one requirement to install`. I don't know what it means and what additional input I have to give? I appreciate your help. Thanks

**Update**: More information on my Raspberry Pi 4 OS

[image]

Python3 version:
[image]

Result of installing pre-required packages:
[image]
[image]

I tried installing VOLLTRON on another Raspberry Pi 4 Model B (2 GB RAM). Unlike the previous one, I did not repeat the installation instructions and install any unnecessary packages. Initially, two packages seem to have been installed without any errors. How do I know? Well, I see two bars (below screenshot). On the video demo, I observed seven bars, meaning that for some reason, five packages failed to install on my RPi board. Then it ended with some errors with text in red color. Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Please tell me what image you used with the raspberry pi?  Noobs, raspian, ubuntu, etc.

Comment: @Craig I think it is Raspbian, a default OS that came with Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. I just update my question with the OS details screenshot of my Raspberry Pi. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a fresh VOLTTRON install on RPI4 but it was running Raspbian version 11.  I had no issues.  I guess make sure you have python3-dev, python3-venv, and build-essential installed via apt prior to bootstrap.

Comment: I appreciate for attempting to install on RPI4 and achieving success. How do I install these? how to make sure these are correctly installed? can you print the code that does all these? Thanks

Comment: Meanwhile, I updated my question with the result of updating/installing all packages. Can you share what was your result when these prerequisite packages were installed? My python was 3.7.

Comment: Did the bootstrap work after the software packages were installed?  I believe it is Python 3.9 on Debian 11 but 3.6 should be fine....

Comment: Please look at the screenshots in my question. They show the result of all installations.  As you can see, the bootstrap seemed did work initially then, lookslike, ended with some error (screenshot in my question). As you know from my question, I performed the VOLTTRON installations so many times, I don't know if that affecting. How do I uninstall and start afresh? Thanks

Comment: On your RPI, do you have just Python 3.9? or do you also have Python 2.7? My understanding is `python3 bootstrap.py` is installing packages using `pip`. But on my machine `pip` refers to the `python2.7`, not `python3.7`. I have to mention `pip3` if it the package is related to `python3.7`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer, I wrote Raspberry PI OS 11 onto a new MicroSD, started and installed it on a spare RPi 3 Model B (1 GB RAM). The OS started well and I had some hiccups due to time mismatch and sync issues. Sorted them out. Also, I installed VOLTTRON successfully without any issues:
I am posting here complete installation steps with screenshots, so this helps any beginner on how to install VOLLTRON on a RPi board:

> Reference:
> https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction/platform-install.html
> Video: [Video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrRQ5LNF2xU&list=PLHz7T-kS6tfM4mGdKyGVP7P7j_So5TqFz&index=9&ab_channel=PNNLUnplugged)

Step0: Some pre-checks before you even proceed to the VOLLTRON. Check the OS version and Python (should be > 3.6)

[image]

Step1: Install prerequisites. Execute the following one by one.

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get full-upgrade 
sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-venv openssl libssl-dev libevent-dev git
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

[image]

Step2: Clone VOLTTRON code. The voltron will download into the home directory.

```
git clone https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron
```

[image]

Step3: Set up virtual environment. Just go for ZMQ bus installation and this is easier and faster to install. I did not install RabbitMQ.

```
cd volttron
python3 bootstrap.py # Coffee is a good to have now. It takes good time. 
source env/bin/activate # activate the volttron platform
```

[image]

Step4: Test the VOLLTRON.

```
# start the volttron
./start-volttron
# vctl stands for volttron control; install an agent (listens to user and controls something) by giving a tag name
vctl install examples/ListenerAgent --tag listener
# now make the agent start/run
vctl start --tag listener
# check the status of listeners 
vctl status
# check the volttron log files
tail -f volttron.log
# to stop the volttron
./stop-volttron
# to deactivate the volttron platform
deactivate
```

[image]
[image]

**Things that did not work or impact the installation:**
There are couple of things that did not work as explained in the installation video.

```
# Each instance to have a voltton home
VOLTTRON_HOME = /opt/volttron/.volttron2 ./start-volttron
```

Result:
[image]
In the above code, the path is directing to a directory or folder called volttron in the opt. I searched and found no directory named volttron in opt. The only location where I have the volttron directory located in my machine is on the very directory cloned from the github volttron account.
[image]